# Not able to extract data from R array

Tags: arrays, r

I am new to R. I have an R array (or atleast I think) which gives the following output

```
> head(x)

    [,1] [,2]
199 3.40 3.50
```

What is the 199 on the front mean? How do I extract the elements of this array?

Comment: It's a row name (`?rownames`).

Comment: Thanks. How do I strip of the rownames?

Comment: `rownames(x) <- NULL`, implied (but not clearly stated) in the help doc in the description of `value`.

Comment: You can basically just ignore the rownames column. It's not included in your data and doesnt modify it. It`s just a orientation for you and you can use it for subsetting: x[199,1] would for example return the element in the first column from row 199.

Comment: @maRtin though you are correct that they do not impact data processing, it is certainly feasible to want to remove them (displaying the data in a report, for example). And no, `x[199,1]` will *not* return the data with respect to the row named "199", it will return the 199th row of the data frame. If you want the specific row, you must quote it, ala `x["199",1]`. (That is, row names are always `character`.)

Comment: @r2vans thanks for the completion. I was of course assuming that the rownames are not labled with strings but are labeled by default from 1:nrow(x).

Comment: Try: `rownames(mtcars) <- 1:32 ; rownames(mtcars)`. Always `character`. Even if this weren't the case, I would caution *strongly* against doing it that way, since the interpreter can't know if you wanted the 199th or the "199" row. (I say this from experience ... it bit me early in my R days, and though it makes sense when you look at it in this context, early in R-learning much of what R does is sprinkled with magic and trust ...)

Answer (score 0):

As above, the 199 is a row name. You extract elements from a data frame (or vector) in R by using square brackets:

```
x[,1] # gives a column
x[1,] # give a row
x[1:2,] # gives several rows
```

You can also use column names like so:

```
x <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c("A", "B", "C"))
x$col1 # 1 2 3
```

You'll figure out more as you start to play around in R and do some R tutorials.